# processing in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, listactivity

i am trying to  show the contents using a list activity in android. 
I am getting a list from backend. now i want to fetch each list value and see whether that item is shown in red color or in green color. this value will also be set in  customVO.

I tried refering to few article on internet like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/). but here they are using List only but i need VO so that i can fetch the value to decide whether that menu item should be red or green.

P.S  i am beginner in android so excuse me if my question seems to be bit stupid. 
thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch each list item"? Do the items already have information about their color (in which case use `getItem(position)` on the adapter), or do you intend to make a web call or something?

Comment: the Arraylist is coming from backend. before showing to user i want them to be painted in different colors according to value in vo for that entry.

Comment: I don't know what VO is. My question is whether the color came with each item when you got them from the server (meaning you have the color information but need a reference to the item object), or do you need to make an additional server call per item.

Comment: yes, that info is in ArrayList<vo>. so i don't need to make any call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just override the getView method to set the background:

```
final ArrayAdapter<MyClass> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyClass>(
        getActivity(), 
        R.layout.list_item, 
        myArray) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        /* Set values of TextViews here */
        MyClass currentItem = getItem(position);
        if (currentItem.getColor() == MyVoClass.GREEN) {
           convertView.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF00);
        } else if (currentItem.getColor() == MyVoClass.RED) {
           convertView.setBackgroundColor(0x00FF0000);
        } else {
           convertView.setBackgroundColor(0x00FFFFFF);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
};
```

Comment: one query... will this " MyClass currentItem = getItem(position);" be called for all the items in the list. or do i   need to use the loop for all the items?

Comment: It will be called for each item.

Comment: You don't have to loop, the ListView asks the Adapter for the items as they are needed. This has the benefit of only rendering views for the visible items rather than all _n_ items in your array. You just describe how to populate the UI fields of a single list item in the getView() method.